# LINQ - Get Max Value of a group of elements

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

How can I use LINQ to query an XML structure and get a max value for a group of elements that belong to a particular element.

For example, how could I get the maximum age allowed for FullTicket, DayTicket and ChildTicket where the XML structure looks like the below

```
    <TicketTypes>
      <TicketType Name="FullTicket">
        <AgeBands>
          <AgeBand>
            <Code>Adult1</Code>
            <MinAge>18</MinAge>
            <MaxAge>59</MaxAge>
          </AgeBand>
          <AgeBand>
            <Code>Adult2</Code>
            <MinAge>60</MinAge>
            <MaxAge>64</MaxAge>
          </AgeBand>
          <AgeBand>
            <Code>Adult3</Code>
            <MinAge>65</MinAge>
            <MaxAge>79</MaxAge>
          </AgeBand>
        </AgeBands>
      </TicketType>
      <TicketType Name="DayTicket">
        <AgeBands>
          <AgeBand>
            <Code>Adult2</Code>
            <MinAge>18</MinAge>
            <MaxAge>64</MaxAge>
          </AgeBand>
          <AgeBand>
            <Code>Adult3</Code>
            <MinAge>65</MinAge>
            <MaxAge>89</MaxAge>
          </AgeBand>
        </AgeBands>
      </TicketType>
      <TicketType Name="ChildTicket">
        <AgeBands>
          <AgeBand>
            <Code>Child</Code>
            <MinAge>3</MinAge>
            <MaxAge>17</MaxAge>
          </AgeBand>
          <AgeBand>
            <Code>Infant</Code>
            <MinAge>0</MinAge>
            <MaxAge>2</MaxAge>
          </AgeBand>
        </AgeBands>
      </TicketType>
    </TicketTypes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want the highest value of MaxAge? (The fact that there's already "max" here is a bit confusing.) Try something like this:

```
// Find the FullTicket element
var fullTicket = ticketTypes.Elements("TicketType")
                     .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == "FullTicket")
                     .First();

// Find the maximum value of any MaxAge element within FullTicket
var maxFullTicketAge = fullTicket.Descendants("MaxAge")
                                 .Max(x => (int) x);
```

You can do the same for the other ticket types, or if you're feeling more adventurous you could do something like:

```
var maxAges = ticketTypes
       .Elements("TicketType")
       .Select(x => new {
                  Name = (string) x.Attribute("Name"),
                  MaxMaxAge = x.Descendants("MaxAge").Max(y => (int) y)
               });
```

Comment: Hate to say it Jon, there's a bug in your code. x.Attribute("Name is missing the ending quote ". Because its you, the C# compiler will mistakingly pick this up. Therefore you need to have a word with Anders to tell him the C# spec needs to be re-written so the above gets compiled ok in future. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: Hi Jon, your more adventurous suggestion was a winner. Thanks. However I have one further question... Say "TicketTypes" was an element belonging to a "Day" element. So you could have "Saturday" and "Sunday" elements each containing a "TicketTypes" element that contains numerous "TicketType" elements. The query above would return multiple Ticket Types. How could I group your query to return the max age for each ticket type over the whole weekend. (i.e. MaxAge grouped by TicketType). Thanks.

Comment: @FloatLeft: Um, I'd have to get my head round that separately I'm afraid :) If you use the same sort of query but using Descendants instead of Elements (from one level higher) and then add a `GroupBy(x => x.Name)` that *might* be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = from item in TicketTypes.Descendants("TicketType")
             from agebands in item.Descendants("AgeBands")
             from ageband in agebands.Descendants("AgeBand")
select item.Attribute("Name"), ageBand.MaxAge;
```